# How do I space flutter widgets in a row for two on the extreme outside, one in the middle?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Looking to align widgets in a row like this: two out the extreme outside edges, one centered

[W1----------W2----------W3]

I need W2 to function as the `Spacer()` does.

Unfortunately `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly/spaceBetween` doesn't quite work for 3 widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap W2 in an expanded.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Widget1(),
    Expanded(child: Widget2()),
    Widget3(),
  ],
),
```

This causes `Widget2` to fill up the remaining spaces after `Widget1` and `Widget3` have been drawn (essentially pushing them to the extreme).

Comment: This was close, it worked when I centered Widget2 as such       Row(
          children: [
            Text('w1'),
            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('center'))),
            Text('w3')
      ]),

Comment: This creates another problem.  I wanted W2 to be centered regardless of W1's size/length.  It is three text widgets, and I want to ellipsis the first widget.

Comment: You can also wrap all 3 in `Expanded` and then tweak their `flex` parameters. That way, they'll have fractional constraints.

Comment: Wrapping them all in Expanded with flex and centering the second widget worked.

Comment: Closed now.  It became a slightly different problem working through these solutions, thanks for the assist.